# Do these word mean the same thing?

Tags: python

I've tried google but found nothing on this topic and my final option was stack overflow.
Does Valid attribute names, Valid attribute reference and Attribute reference mean the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, probably putting "valid" as a prefix is just a way to affirmate that you have to create an attribute reference that makes sense or just to follow good habits.

There goes a post to good habits when creating variables/references:

https://towardsdatascience.com/data-scientists-your-variable-names-are-awful-heres-how-to-fix-them-89053d2855be